# Disable download link on Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox with my Rev Slider plugin on my Wordpress site.  The video I have linked pops up and works and plays properly.  However, in the bottom right corner of the popup is a link to download the video.  The video is playing from Vimeo and I have my Vimeo settings set to not allow downloads.  I can't find any settings to remove that button.

[The button I want to remove from the Fancybox popup is circled in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcbrs.jpg)

Comment: A picture might help here.

Comment: @javabrett  I edited the original post to include a link to an image.  The download button is circled in red and that's the button I want to disable.

Comment: And where is the code you are using to see the video in fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Fancybox2 Vimeo example at http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples - it has no download button showing, in fact I think all the Vimeo player controls are hidden as you might expect.